# Regex for splitting string into a collection of two based on a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Using the C# Regex.Split method, I would like to split strings that will always start with RepXYZ, Where the XYZ bit is a number that will always have either 3 or 4 characters.

Examples

1. "Rep1007$chkCheckBox"
2. "Rep127_Group_Text"

The results should be:

1. {"Rep1007","$chkCheckBox"}
2. {"Rep127","_Group_Text"}

So far I have tried (Rep)[\d]{3,4} and ((Rep)[\d]{3,4})+ but both of those are giving me unwanted results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Regex.Split` often results in empty or unwanted items in the resulting array. Using `(Rep)[\d]{3,4}` in `Regex.Split`, will put `Rep` without the numbers into the resulting array.  `(Rep[\d]{3,4})` will put the `Rep` and the numbers into the result, but since the match is at the start, there will be an empty item in the array.

I suggest using `Regex.Match` here:

```
var match = Regex.Match(text, @"^(Rep\d+)(.*)$");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28Rep%5Cd%2B%29%28.*%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=Rep1007%24chkCheckBox%0D%0ARep127_Group_Text&o=m)

[image]

Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(Rep\d+)` - capturing group 1: `Rep` and any one or more digits
- `(.*)` - capturing group 2: any one or more chars other than a newline, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

A splitting approach is better implemented with a lookaround-based regex:

```
var results = Regex.Split(text, @"(?<=^Rep\d+)(?=[$_])");
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5ERep%5Cd%2B%29%28%3F%3D%5B%24_%5D%29&i=Rep127_Group_Text&o=m).

`(?<=^Rep\d+)(?=[$_])` splits a string at the location that is immediately preceded with `Rep` and one or more digits at the start of the string, and immediately followed with `$` or `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting on the regex pattern on either `$` or `_`:

```
string input = "Rep127_Group_Text";
string[] parts = input.Split(new[] { '$', '_' }, 2);
foreach (string part in parts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```

This prints:

```
Rep127
Group_Text
```

Comment: Your regex [won't work](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3d%5b%24_%5d%29&i=Rep1007%24chkCheckBox%0d%0aRep127_Group_Text&r=%0d%0a&o=m) with `Rep127_Group_Text`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I fixed it, at least for the sample data given.  There doesn't seem to be any API way to stop `Regex.Split` from splitting on every occurrence (unlike regular regex string split).